Gitlab self managed instance restore
I have a gitlab ee self managed instance (Version 16.8.1) which is now up and running. I have taken full backup of it using.
• sudo gitlab-backup create
I got the backup and it contains every files i hope, including the repositories. Now i need to restore it to a new server which i have installed as fresh and setup with same version as the running or source gitlab instance.
Then i performed the restoration steps as mentioned in this document. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/restore_gitlab.html#:~:text=NFS%20mounts.-,Restore%20for%20Linux%20package%20installations,-This%20procedure%20assumes
Moved the backup file to /var/opt/gitlab/backups
Renamed it with ending _gitlab_backup.tar
Made git as the owner for this folder Stopped puma and sidekiq then performed the restore command
#sudo gitlab-backup restore BACKUP="my backup file name excluding _giltab_backup.tar"
The restoration step is working, by the way an error is showing in the first when database clearing is performed
Restoring PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production … ERROR: must be owner of extension pg_trgm ERROR: must be owner of extension btree_gist ERROR: must be owner of extension btree_gist ERROR: must be owner of extension pg_trgm
After this the restoration is compled. Then i replaced the destination gitlab instance gitlab.rb and secrets.json with source server file of the same name.
After that i restart the gitlab instance.
When gitlab instance is up i could able to login, my ssl works,projects,users all are listing as fine. But when i open any project it is showing ‘no repository’
When i check the /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories It is containing only +gitaly folder. no @groups or @hashed folder. Which is there in the backup file i double checked.
Then i manually copied the @groups and @hashed folders to /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories and restart and reconfigure the gitlab but no luck,still the same.
then i performed sudo gitlab-rake cache:clear still no luck.
What is the issue, am i missing anything or is this a known with some altrenative solutions. Can anyone help me.


Remember to stop puma & sidekiq before running the database restore:

gitlab-ctl stop puma
gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq


The data directories need to be owned by git:git

root@gitlab:~# ll /var/opt/gitlab/git-data
total 112K
drwx------    3 git  git    25 Nov 10  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x   28 root root 4.0K Sep 19 10:13 ..
drwxrws--- 2449 git  git   64K Sep 23 15:07 repositories


Run gitlab-ctl tail xxxx on every service shown by gitlab-ctl status (to check for permission errors)
Restoring from an old backup (where some uid's had changed) - I also needed to:

# fix permissions
-----------------
chown -R gitlab-prometheus:gitlab-prometheus  /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data*
chown -R gitlab-www:gitlab-www /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/proxy_cache/*
chown -R gitlab-prometheus:gitlab-prometheus /var/opt/gitlab/alertmanager/data


the initial database errors can be ignored

